# FBAR filing for first time as H1B- need help on some queries

Tags: united-states, income-tax, h-1b-visa, fbar

I am on h1b and have been working in US for more than a couple of years now. I came to know  recently that FBAR is required to be filled. Subsequently, I started researching about it and trying to fill out the form. It's a little overwhelming and have some queries.

1. How do I calculate my highest account value of stocks for a particular year from my demat account for 2020 and 2021? I didn't sell any stocks in these years. I did earn some dividend income which I will not down wherever required. There's no way for me to know what was the highest investment value of the account in 2020 and 2021 as they keep fluctuating everyday.
2. Similar to above, how do I know the highest value of my mutual funds for 2020 and 2021.
3. I am planning to fill fbar for 2020 and 2021 this year as I wasn't aware that this is required to be filled. What should be the right response as to FBAR being filed late for 2020 without getting penalties?
4. Do i need to amend my tax return for 2020 to include my Indian account interest earnings? If yes, does this need to be done first before filing FBAR?
5. Is ULIP insurance also required to be reported?
6. I pay insurance premium in lumpsum and has a tenure of 10 years of payment, and it matures in 15 years. Does this need to be reported as well?

Apologies that I have asked so many queries in one post so as to keep it in one place. I have searched in forums and websites, but the above questions are somewhat specific and I didn't get a clear picture. Also, I am not in a position to hire a CPA and have to do it on my own.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I calculate my highest account value of stocks for a particular year from my demat account for 2020 and 2021?

I'd suggest going by your statements and finding the highest value reported on your statements during the year. If you get no statements at all and made no transactions, then go with either year-end or year-start (the highest), but that would be an approximation.

From FinCEN [instructions](https://www.fincen.gov/reporting-maximum-account-value):

> The maximum value of an account is a reasonable approximation of the greatest value of currency or nonmonetary assets in the account during the calendar year. Periodic account statements may be relied on to determine the maximum value of the account, provided that the statements fairly reflect the maximum account value during the calendar year.

> I am planning to fill fbar for 2020 and 2021 this year as I wasn't aware that this is required to be filled. What should be the right response as to FBAR being filed late for 2020 without getting penalties?

That may be a problem since the penalties are pretty steep. I'd suggest talking to a professional EA/CPA/Tax Attorney specializing in delinquent FBARs.

> Do i need to amend my tax return for 2020 to include my Indian account interest earnings? If yes, does this need to be done first before filing FBAR?

Absolutely. The FBAR non-filing penalties are significantly higher if there's undisclosed income related to the undisclosed accounts. The whole purpose of FBAR is to curtail tax evasion.

> Is ULIP insurance also required to be reported?

I believe so, it's a form of investment from my understanding and has a cash value.

> I pay insurance premium in lumpsum and has a tenure of 10 years of payment, and it matures in 15 years. Does this need to be reported as well?

Do you pay insurance premiums while in the US? Then you may be liable for an additional excise tax ([IRC Sec. 4371](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/4371)).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Am now worried that you say penalties will be levied. I came to know about FBAR only recently. Yes, i pay insurance premiums while in the US, you mentioned that is also an additional tax. How do i get help for all of this? Any pointers where I can look for a tax attorney who won't charge me a limb and could be cost effective? Another query - How to report my interest income for years 2019, 2020?

Comment: @Sid Interest income goes on Schedule B of your tax return. Same schedule is also used to mark existence of foreign accounts and that FBAR is required. You should hire a EA/CPA/Tax Attorney experienced with expats, ask for referrals from people you know, IMHO it's the best way.